# logic arguments

Tags: logic

If today is Morgan's birthday then today is October 16. Today is October 16. Hence today is Morgan's birthday. I knew that it can be true or false. then
My question is that Today is Morgan's birthday statement is true or false?

Comment: *"Today is Morgan's birthday"* can be true or false. The *"Hence"* is incorrect

Comment: Regarding your selection of the "limits" tag, you may want to explain how this question fits into the topic of limits. I don't see the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textit{Today is Morgan's birthday} \implies \textit{Today is October 16}$

It's not an $\textit{if and only if } (\iff)$ so it's false.

If today is October 16, then it may or may not be Morgan's birthday.

Note: this is a weird example, because in real life it should be an $\textit{if and only if.}$

Comment: Thank you. How can i prove or disprove this statement???

Answer (score 2):

If we are *only* given that *if today is Morgan's birthday then today is October 16* and *today is October 16* (in other words, if we forget everything else we know about dates and birthdays), then we cannot conclude that *today is Morgan's birthday*.

This argument has the format

$$\begin{align}&p\Rightarrow q\\&q\\\therefore\; &p\end{align}$$

which is the fallacy of [affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

The problem is that it is difficult to view this particular example without implicitly incorporating additional knowledge of dates and birthdays...

---

To say that an argument

$$p_1\\p_2\\\vdots\\p_n\\\therefore q$$

is *valid* is to say that the proposition $\displaystyle\mathop\land_{k=1}^np_k\Rightarrow q$ is a tautology.

Thus, to demonstrate that an argument is not valid, we just need to show that $\displaystyle\mathop\land_{k=1}^np_k\Rightarrow q$ is *not* a tautology.

To show that *affirming the consequent* is not a valid argument, then, we just need to show that the proposition $\left((p\Rightarrow q) \land q\right)\Rightarrow p$ is not a tautology (which is easy enough: consider the case $p$ false, $q$ true).

Compare this to [*modus ponens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens):

$$\begin{align}&p\Rightarrow q\\&p\\\therefore\; &q\end{align}$$

Notice that this argument is *valid*: in other words, the proposition $\left((p\Rightarrow q) \land p\right)\Rightarrow q$ is a tautology.

Comment: Thank you. How can i prove or disprove this statement?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address this question. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the State $Morgens Birthday$ is only true under the condition the Date `Oct16` is true is called a Subjunction

$$ Morgans Birthday \, \implies \, Oct16 $$

if  $October 16th \; = true $ it does not matter if $Morgans Birthday$ is `true` or `false`, the statement in itself is `true` either way. However you can not backward imply that $Morgans Birthday$ is `true` or `false` for the same reason, simply because you can't know. Subjunctions are one way streets.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B & A\implies B \\ \hline
T & T& T\\ \hline
T & F& F\\ \hline
F & T& T\\ \hline
F & F& T\end{array}

Comment: Thank you. How can i prove or disprove this statement?

Comment: MorgansBirthday∧October16=1
MorgansBirthday∧~October16=0
Is this second line correct??                 ~MorgansBirthday∧October16=0. is this one correct ??

Comment: based on this, you can use the $Distributive \, Law$ $((A ⟹ B) ⟺ (\lnot A \lor B))$ and $de'Morgans \, Law$ to convert your statements to a logic equivalent and prove or disprove them.